# Is there an IDE for javascript development with Google's Javascript APIs?

Tags: javascript

Is there an IDE for development with Google Javascript APIs specifically with autocomplete etc?

GWT only allows you to use Java or Python, but what if I wish to use javascript for native app development with Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

i just using *NetBeans*, add reference script to google and try to code. 
However you cannot copy *Google Javascript APIs* to local, i have try it :)

thanks.

Comment: and how exactly do u do that, is it possible on eclipse?

Comment: sorry my previous comment not complete.
here is:


same with eclipse, for example i used google Annotated Time Line,
just add a reference 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
for detail you can see the detail in http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html
for my example.

Answer (score 0):

Google just released the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/). This might help you.

Comment: well, the plugin allows help for Java Developers.